# How to set data for steps of Cucumber .feature file from .properties file

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I have next expressions in  Cucumber feature file :

```
Feature: Some text

Background: This indicates that the server is up and running

Given the APIs are up and running for "https://localhost: ............"
```

I want to moved and keep this URL in file.properties . How  I can get this URL from .properties file to .feature file

Answer (score 0):

you can try [qaf-gherkin](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html) it supports properties. With qaf-gherkin your feature file may look like below:

```
Feature: Some text

Background: This indicates that the server is up and running

Given the APIs are up and running for "${base.url}"
```

You can have `base.url` property in property file. Furthermore it has [web service automation support](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support-ws/wiki) as well for web services automation which has web service call repository concept and parameterization support.